# SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading

Tags: ssl, curl

I have a curl call in a dockerfle which downloads some binaries,and was working just fine.
But suddenly it stopped working with error:

```
RUN curl -fSL https://archive.apache.org/dist//nifi/1.22.0/nifi-toolkit-1.22.0-bin.zip 
...
...
#0 45.23 curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
```

On running following in terminal:

```
curl -v https://archive.apache.org/dist//nifi/1.22.0/nifi-toolkit-1.22.0-bin.zip
```

I see this:

```
* Trying 65.108.204.189...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to archive.apache.org (65.108.204.189) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to archive.apache.org:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to archive.apache.org:443
```

What may have gone wrong?